# MVC3 LINQ multiple INNER JOIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to use two INNER JOIN by using

```
var product = from a in db.Product.Include(a => a.Category).Include(a => a.Model)
select a;

return View(product.ToList());
```

If I write the above coding, it has error in return View(product.ToList());

Error said, 'More than one item in the metadata collection match the identity 'Model'.'

When I try to debug with

```
var product = from a in db.Product.Include(a => a.Category)
select a;
```

I can see the SQL query as

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[productId] AS [productId], 
[Extent1].[categoryId] AS [categoryId], 
[Extent1].[modelId] AS [modelId], 
[Extent1].[model] AS [model], 
[Extent1].[displaySize] AS [displaySize], 
[Extent1].[processor] AS [processor], 
[Extent1].[ramSize] AS [ramSize], 
[Extent1].[capacityType] AS [capacityType], 
[Extent1].[capacity] AS [capacity], 
[Extent1].[colour] AS [colour], 
[Extent1].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[price] AS [price], 
[Extent1].[threeDayPrice] AS [threeDayPrice], 
[Extent1].[aWeekPrice] AS [aWeekPrice], 
[Extent1].[twoWeekPrice] AS [twoWeekPrice], 
[Extent1].[aMonthPrice] AS [aMonthPrice], 
[Extent1].[threeMonthPrice] AS [threeMonthPrice], 
[Extent1].[sixMonthPrice] AS [sixMonthPrice], 
[Extent1].[stock] AS [stock], 
[Extent2].[categoryId] AS [categoryId1], 
[Extent2].[name] AS [name]
FROM  [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[categoryId] = [Extent2].[categoryId]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[model] ASC}
```

I want to add INNER JOIN to Model entity through modelId as foreign key.

How it is possible?

Thanks.

--Added model--

```
--Prodruct.cs--

public class Product
{
[Key] public int productId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select category")]
public int categoryId { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select model")]
public int modelId { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Model name")]
public String model { get; set; }

public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}

--Category.cs--
public class Category
{
[Key] public int categoryId { get; set; }
public String name { get; set; }
}

--Model.cs--
public class Model
{
[Key] public int modelId { get; set; }
public String name { get; set; }
}

--RentalDB.cs--
public class rentalDB : DbContext
{
public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
public DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }
public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
public DbSet<Cart> Cart { get; set; }
public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the domain model?

Comment: With `Include` you often get different result when the order of includes is changed. Did you try that? And when you add two includes only one of them (or even zero) will be inner join.

Answer (score 0):

In my test database, I ran this in LinqPad

```
from a in Products.Include("Categories").Include("Suppliers") select a
```

And I got this generated sql:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
[Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
... Lots of stuff ...
FROM   [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[SupplierID] = [Extent3].[SupplierID]
```

In my environment, there's no overload for include receiving a lambda expression, you probably got it from somewhere so I don't know what going on with your include, try changing your query to

```
var product = from a in db.Product.Include("Category").Include("Model") select a;
```

Comment: It's an extension method in the System.Data.Entity namespace.